# sensor time stamp calculation error

Tags: android, time, android-sensors

There are many questions relating to understanding the time stamp in sensor event.
I tried my own way as follow to get the real event time in nano second:
`(System.currentTimeMillis()-SystemClock.uptimeMillis() )*1000000 + event.timestamp`

`System.currentTimeMillis()-SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`
This is to get the system start time in millis.

`System.currentTimeMillis()-SystemClock.uptimeMillis()*1000000`
Make it in nano second.

The whole idea is system start time + uptime to event.

I use the following to debug:
`Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Hongkong"));
cl.setTimeInMillis( ( (System.currentTimeMillis()-SystemClock.uptimeMillis() )*1000000 + event.timestamp) /1000000);`

`Log.v(LOGTAG, "event happened at: " + cl.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + ":"
    + (cl.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " "
    + cl.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
    + cl.get(Calendar.SECOND));`

What is get is the time with error, same date with about half an hour later.
Because not one hour error, I assume it is not related to timezone.

Hope to see suggestion.
Thank

Comment: suddenly the error go to 20 hours

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to ROM bug.
This is a non official ROM and with a quick restart function.
It resets system up time but not event time stamp.
When just after system quick restart, event time stamp is not 0/1 this kind of small number, instead, it is the nano second since your last real / hard reboot.